# How high will the Crew Dragon capsule get during the In-Flight Abort?

Tags: launch, testing, dragon-v2, abort

During the In-Flight Abort test (IFA), the Crew Dragon capsule will pull away from the Falcon 9 rocket when the rocket is undergoing maximum aerodynamic stress. At that time, it will still be going pretty fast, and it will pick up some speed from the abort motors firing. How high do we expect the capsule to actually get?